# What is the clear meaning of ‘rather’ in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He was the one who imposed the ***rather*** strict regulations for
> academic employment.

What is the clear meaning of *rather* in the above sentence? I want it to mean something like ‘quite’ or ‘pretty’. Does it mean so? Different meanings of *rather* have made me confused about my usage.

Comment: _Rather_ doesn't have a clear meaning. It's used to emphasize to an underspecified degree. I.e, it's sposta be vague. It means the writer disapproves of the regulations.

Comment: @JohnLawler Whether the write disapproves or not is not clear. The same could have been written approvingly by a strict martinet.

Comment: @Anton How about "the writer is willing to allow us to believe they disapprove". I said it's vague.

Comment: Agreed. It is rather vague in both directions.

Comment: @JohnLawler Which one then? does the writer imply via using ‘rather’ that she disapproves the regulations, or not?

Comment: "Imply"? No. Maybe an invited inference, but even that's too strong. A suspicion, perhaps; and always in context (which we do not have).

Answer (score 3):

It means *somewhat*. It's an intensifier that is less intense than *very*, and even less intense than *quite*.

[M-W *rather*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather)
5 : in some degree : *somewhat*
it's *rather* warm
—often used as a mild intensive
spent *rather* a lot of money